# How to view logs online during heavy usage with screen, tmux or Byobu?

Tags: bash, ssh, tmux, byobu

Normally I use `tail -F`, but on heavy usage it is getting irresponsible and unreadable.

On ssh I also use buyobu to type password only once. But when any of screens become irresponsible then all screens are blocked. And I can not kill any screen by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> nor <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. That why I don’t know how to use [Byoubu](http://byobu.co) for all of my needs.

I would like to see something like: `tail -F` but which skips efficiently what is above that given rate (f.ex.: 4 pages per 500ms).

Ideally would be in cycles printing X pages and skipping for Y time and then printing last X pages of text but only those which are new.

Does anyone know any tool or command combination to achieve this? Or I need to write my script or program?

Quick but partial solution during "tail freeze":

- detach from byoubu (F6)
- killall tail
- go back to byobu (will preserve previous layout)

Comment: Could try `kill -STOP` tail for a while...

Comment: But still to execute kill I have to create new terminal. It should be possible to do it on byobu. "Remove split" may work but usually I am on other split. "Kill current window" kills all so it is not good.

Comment: Would suspend with CTRL-Z work? It sends the same  `-STOP` signal if I'm not mistaken. But you said ctrl-c & ctrl-d don't work, so maybe this won't either

Comment: I would work same as ctrl-c/ctrl-d only if you are on this particular split where the logs are attacking. Any more complicated case results I no response.

Answer (score 1):

`less` seems to give me a static "snapshot" of a text file.

If the file is subsequently added to, pressing <kbd>End</kbd> (and probably some other combinations too) will re-load the "new" end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Advice for writing a script:

Make a script that remembers the last offset, tail for at most 4x80 lines from that point, adjust your last offset and wait 500ms.

Counting new lines rate example can be useful: [link](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/5490/lines-per-second-in-a-log-file)